# React Navigation v5 use drawer to filter details on screen

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

i want to use the drawer navigator to filter items on a screen by passing parameters from the `App` function to the `Home` screen whenever the `getFilters` function is triggered, am i going about this the wrong way?

```
export default function App() {
  const [filters, setFilters] = React.useState([]);

  getFilters = (filterArr) => {
    setFilters(filterArr)
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} func={this.getFilters} />}>
        <Drawer.Screen 
        name="Home" 
        component={HomeScreen}
        initialParams={{theFilters:filters}}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={FavesScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

My app has a drawer navigator where i've added drop down pickers, the user can select items and i'm hoping it filters the results shown on the home screen.

My issue is that i have no idea how to send the data to the home screen here

```
<Drawer.Screen 
    name="Home" 
    component={HomeScreen}
    initialParams={{theFilters:filters}}/>
```

if i hard code initialParams={{theFilters:"filters"}} it works fine. But i don't want to just set an initialParam, **i want the screen to be re-rendered whenever the getFilters function is called**.

If i add an alert in the getFilters function, it works as expected, showing an alert with all the filters the user has chosen so the data is definitely there.
I can provide more detail if needed

Answer (score 0):

if you just wanna update your component you can use useLayoutEffect, you set a value in this case 'filters' in the function and it will render your component
here is an example:

```
  useLayoutEffect(()=>{
    this.getFilters()
    }
  },[filters])
```

and you will see your component with your updated data

Comment: I cant access the getFilters function from my home screen, thats the issue, do you know how to pass it to the screen?

Comment: Thanks for your help! i solved it myself, may not be the right way but if you share the example i'll definitely give it a try if its more practical than my solution.

Comment: you need to execute your getFilters function in your HomeScreen component?, I deleted my question because maybe I misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

Used a cheeky work around, instead of trying to pass the function down to the component, i used @react-native-community/async-storage.

Made the setFilters function store the data to the users phone, and in my home function, added an event listener so when the user closes the navigation drawer its state is updated with the contents of the async storage getItem function.

Quite nice as now the user can completely close the app and the product page will be filtered for them unless they use the reset button